# Should I edit a user meta field with PUT, PATCH, or POST and WP::Editable

Tags: ajax, wp-api, rest-api

I have a simple `CPT` called `App` in the backend.

I have added a custom `usermeta` field called `favorite_apps` to `Users`

On the front end, I show a list of apps, and then the user presses a star(☆) icon to add it to their list of favorites ( stored as an array of `post_id` in the `favorite_apps` custom user meta field ).

I decided to do this using the REST API and built a custom endpoint:

`/wp-json/my-site/v1/users/{user_id}/favoriteapps`

Example: `/wp-json/my-site/v1/users/555/favoriteapps`

This route accepts `POST,PUT,PATCH` using `WP::Editable` and `GET` using `WP::Readable`.

A `GET` request returns a list of user `555`'s current `favorite_apps`

A `POST` request, and pass `app=123` in the body I add the App ID `123` to `app_favorites`

For removing an app from the list, I'm not sure. I'm not DELETING the list of favorite_apps, I'm removing one of the items.

It feels natural to use `POST` and `DELETE` to add/remove from the list, but:

1. Is there a **convention** that I can follow when modifying a list of items?
2. Should I be using `PUT` or `PATCH` and passing an `action` as another parameter?
3. Do I have to be concerned about **browser support** for certain methods?

For reference, this is how I add app `123` to/from user `555` in js/jQuery:

```
var uid = 555;
var appId = 123;
$.ajax({
    method : 'POST',
    data   : { app : 123 },
    url    : '/wp-json/my-site/v1/users/' + uid + '/favoriteapps',
        success: function( data ){
            // code to tell user of success or failure;
        }
});
```

Comment: I've answered my own question below, but if anyone has input, feel free to add it. I'm opting not to use `PUT` but rely on `POST` and `DELETE` to different endpoints. Once I wrote it down, it make complete sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, with some great examples from : https://restfulapi.net/resource-naming/ and http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/restfulresourcenaming.html I'm going to answer my own question.

**ESSENTIALLY**, for my use case, I will NOT use `PUT` but rely on `POST` and `DELETE` to collection and singleton endpoints.

## Notes:

1. I've omitted the `wp-json/my-site-namespace/v1` prepending examples
   for clarity
2. I've used query strings in POST requests but for clarity, but I'd submit them in the POST body as POST vars and NOT in the query string.

## Use `GET` Requests on single entities or collections

```
// Gets a collection of users
GET /users 

// Gets the singleton users 3
GET /users/3/favoriteapps

// Gets a collection of user 3 favorite apps
GET /users/3/favoriteapps
```

### Use `POST` requests only on collection endpoints ( makes sense )

```
// Create a new user named Joe ( returns the ID )
POST /users?name=Joe ( pass in required params in POST vars )

// Add app 123 to user's favorite apps. Technically, I'm not CREATING
// a new favorite app, which is where I was getting hung up, but 
// in context of user 3, I AM creating a new reference to an existing app

POST /users/3/favoriteapps?app_id=123  ( pass in required app id in POST vars )
```

### USE `PUT` requests to edit a collection or an entity

In my case, I'm adding and removing known apps to and from the user, so I would NOT support `PUT` in my implementation, but if I DID implement it I would implement it only on the collection, maybe if I was passing a collection and comparing that collection with what is existing.

```
// Edit ( replace ) existing apps with list of apps for user 3
PUT /users/3/favoriteapps?apps=123,321,444,111,33

// In my use case, I wouldn't ONLY support PUT to a new favoriteapps
// base url, outside of the user context This would but this would 
// change the app title for app 123 ( obviously for all users' collections )
PUT /favoriteapps/123?title=New+App+Title
```

### Use `DELETE` requests on single entity endpoints (mostly)**

** Using DELETE on a collection endpoint should delete the whole collection (semantically speaking), which is rarely what you intend. but in some cases, like a clear button to reset the collection to 0 items, you could use it.

```
// Remove app `123` from favoriteapps collection of user 3
DELETE /users/3/favoriteapps/123

// note: this is another area I got hung up, as I'm not DELETING app 123
// However, in context of user 3, I AM removing it from that user's collection
```